# Am unable to subclass SKSpriteNode using an image name

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am having trouble subclassing SKSpriteNode when I need to use an .png image and all the help I can find on Google only mentions SKTexture.

In my regular class this code works:

```
let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "slot")
circle.setScale(1.0)
circle.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
circle.position = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 500)
self.addChild(circle)
```

I would like to move it to a subclass, but no matter what combination I try am always getting errors such as:

> Cannot convert value of type 'SKTexture' to expected argument type
> 'String'

or

> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'SKSpriteNode'

I am able to subclass SKSpriteNode if I want to use SKTexture. Yet at this juncture the init I want to subclass is `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: String)`

***Here is what I am trying to do, but of course I get errors***

```
class MyBall : SKSpriteNode{
    init(iNamed: String){
        super.init(imageNamed: iNamed)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you subclassing the SKSpriteNode class itself, providing a default argument to the SKSpriteNode initializer?

Comment: @Andreas I thought I put in a sample of the code I am trying to work off of, just added it to the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the full initializer on the super, like so...

```
class MyBall : SKSpriteNode{

    init(iNamed: String) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: iNamed)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: texture.size())
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: While that works, isn't SKTexture different from an image file?

Comment: There is 2 things, First your problem is that "init(imageNamed name: String)" is a "convenience" initialisez. And you can not use a convenience initialiser to init a super class. You must used (by opposition)  a "designated initialiser" as the error suggest.
The second point is that the convenience initialiser is actually getting the texture from the image file and creating the object with the texture. That's why you must do it yourself when you subclass SKSpriteNode. Finally, a texture is an image. but not all image format can be interpreted as textures